# Why doesn't my external JavaScript file work when I load my html page?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I separated my html and JavaScript code. I placed my JavaScript code into a separate file and use 'script' tags to reference it in my html file. I have two functions within my JavaScript code one is used to create an autofill which means if I start typing text within a text box the function gives me a possible name that I may be wanting to write underneath the text box and the other creates a clock that gives the current time. Here are my JavaScript and html files respectively. Can you tell me what the problem is?

```
function Complete(obj, evt) {
    var names = new Array("albert","alessandro","chris");
    names.sort();

    if ((!obj) || (!evt) || (names.length == 0)) {
        return;
    }
    if (obj.value.length == 0) {
        return;
    }

    var elm = (obj.setSelectionRange) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;

    if ((elm < 32) || (elm >= 33 && elm <= 46) || (elm >= 112 && elm <= 123)) {
        return;
    }

    var txt = obj.value.replace(/;/gi, ",");
    elm = txt.split(",");
    txt = elm.pop();
    txt = txt.replace(/^\s*/, "");

    if (txt.length == 0) {
        return;
    }

    if (obj.createTextRange) {
        var rng = document.selection.createRange();
        if (rng.parentElement() == obj) {
            elm = rng.text;
            var ini = obj.value.lastIndexOf(elm);
        }
    } else if (obj.setSelectionRange) {
        var ini = obj.selectionStart;
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
        elm = names[i].toString();
        if (elm.toLowerCase().indexOf(txt.toLowerCase()) == 0) {
            obj.value += elm.substring(txt.length, elm.length);
            break;
        }
    }

    if (obj.createTextRange) {
        rng = obj.createTextRange();
        rng.moveStart("character", ini);
        rng.moveEnd("character", obj.value.length);
        rng.select();
    } else if (obj.setSelectionRange) {
        obj.setSelectionRange(ini, obj.value.length);
    }
}

function tick() {
    var hours, minutes, seconds, ap;
    var intHours, intMinutes, intSeconds;
    var today;

    today = new Date();

    intHours = today.getHours();
    intMinutes = today.getMinutes();
    intSeconds = today.getSeconds();

    switch(intHours){
        case 0: 
            intHours = 12;
            hours = intHours+":";
            ap = "A.M.";
            break;
        case 12:
            hours = intHours+":";
            ap = "P.M.";
            break;
        case 24:
            intHours = 12;
            hours = intHours + ":";
            ap = "A.M.";
            break;
        default: 
            if (intHours > 12) {
                intHours = intHours - 12;
                hours = intHours + ":";
                ap = "P.M.";
                break;
            }
        if(intHours < 12) {
            hours = intHours + ":";
            ap = "A.M.";
        }
    }

    if (intMinutes < 10) {
        minutes = "0"+intMinutes+":";
    } else {
        minutes = intMinutes+":";
    }
    if (intSeconds < 10) {
        seconds = "0"+intSeconds+" ";
    } else {
        seconds = intSeconds+" ";
    } 

    timeString = hours+minutes+seconds+ap;
    Clock.innerHTML = timeString;
    window.setTimeout("tick();", 100);
}
window.onload = tick;
```

```html
<HTML>
    <HEAD>
    <H1 STYLE="text-align:center;" STYLE="font-family:verdana;">FDM Markets</H1>
    <H2 STYLE="text-align:center;">Trading Platofrm</H2></br>

    <STYLE type="text/css">
        #p1 span {
            width: 65px;
            display: block;
            float: left;
        }
    </STYLE>

    <BODY>
        <SCRIPT type="text/javascript" src="jscodeloginpage.js"></SCRIPT>
        <p1>Login</p1></br>
        </br>
        <FORM name="anyForm">
            Username: <input type="text" name="anyName" size="15" onKeyUp="Complete(this, event)"></br>
            Password: <input type="text" size="15" name="password_box">
        </FORM>

        <div id=Clock style=font-size: 12">&nbsp;</div>
    </BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: Why don't you tell **us** what the problem is?  What doesn't work?  What happens when you load your page?  Do you see errors in the console?  Can you tell from the network tools in the browser whether your script file is actually loaded?

Comment: Hi! Relative to the HTML document, where is the JS script stored? in the same directory? You may need a `/` before `jscodeloginpage.js` in your `src` attribute? is there an error in your browser's console?

Comment: You shouldn't have `<h1>` and `<h2>` in `<head>`. You should close the `<head>` as well.

Comment: I also recommend using lowercase for all tags and attributes

Comment: No error appears nothing. The onyl thing that comes up is my html content but no clock showing current time or auto fill doesnt work either. THATS the problem.

Comment: JS is stored in the same directory as html file

Comment: by the way the break isnt missplaced each case deserves a break statement except for the last case for obvious reasons.

Comment: No, your right. I think the break statement is missplaced. I changed it but it still doesnt work

Comment: We're not machines, we're developers. Start using the widely supported `Event.key` or `Event.code` instead of `Event.keyCode` or `Event.which`. It will make your code more expressive and readable.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I put your code into **[a jsbin](http://jsbin.com/ehiyik/3/edit)**. Most issues were found with help of it's code debugger / error console.

You had a few variables that were out of scope, meaning:

```
if(x){
    var a = 1;
}
if(y){
    doSomethingWith(a);
    /* 
     * JavaScript can't access `a` here, since it was declared in the scope of the
     * previous `if`. That instance of `a` only exists within that first `if`.
     */
}
```

You had a misplaced `break` in your `switch/case`'s `default` section, and some other minor issues.

See the **[jsbin](http://jsbin.com/ehiyik/3/edit)** I linked to for a **working example**. I also made some modifications to your HTML. This line:

```
<div id=Clock style=font-size: 12">&nbsp;</div>
```

Was missing a few `"`'s:

```
<div id="Clock" style="font-size: 12">&nbsp;</div>
```

Also, `</br>` isn't a valid tag, you were probably looking for `<br />`

Here's your edited JS:

```
function Complete(obj, evt) {
    var names = new Array("albert","alessandro","chris");
    names.sort();

    var elm = (obj.setSelectionRange) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;

    if (!obj ||
        !evt ||
        names.length === 0 ||
        obj.value.length === 0 ||
        elm < 32 ||
        (elm >= 33 && elm <= 46) ||
        (elm >= 112 && elm <= 123)) {
        return;
    }

    var txt = obj.value.replace(/;/gi, ",");
    elm = txt.split(",");
    txt = elm.pop();
    txt = txt.replace(/^\s*/, "");

    if (txt.length === 0) {
        return;
    }

    var ini, rng;
    if (obj.createTextRange) {
        rng = document.selection.createRange();
        if (rng.parentElement() == obj) {
            elm = rng.text;
            ini = obj.value.lastIndexOf(elm);
        }
    } else if (obj.setSelectionRange) {
        ini = obj.selectionStart;
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
        elm = names[i].toString();
        if (elm.toLowerCase().indexOf(txt.toLowerCase()) === 0) {
            obj.value += elm.substring(txt.length, elm.length);
            break;
        }
    }

    if (obj.createTextRange) {
        rng = obj.createTextRange();
        rng.moveStart("character", ini);
        rng.moveEnd("character", obj.value.length);
        rng.select();
    } else if (obj.setSelectionRange) {
        obj.setSelectionRange(ini, obj.value.length);
    }
}

function tick() {
    var hours, minutes, seconds, ap;
    var intHours, intMinutes, intSeconds;
    var today;

    today = new Date();

    intHours = today.getHours();
    intMinutes = today.getMinutes();
    intSeconds = today.getSeconds();

    switch(intHours){
        case 0: 
            intHours = 12;
            hours = intHours+":";
            ap = "A.M.";
            break;
        case 12:
            hours = intHours+":";
            ap = "P.M.";
            break;
        case 24:
            intHours = 12;
            hours = intHours + ":";
            ap = "A.M.";
            break;
        default: 
            if (intHours > 12) {
                intHours = intHours - 12;
                hours = intHours + ":";
                ap = "P.M.";
            }
            if(intHours < 12) {
                hours = intHours + ":";
                ap = "A.M.";
            }
            break;
    }

    if (intMinutes < 10) {
        minutes = "0"+intMinutes+":";
    } else {
        minutes = intMinutes+":";
    }
    if (intSeconds < 10) {
        seconds = "0"+intSeconds+" ";
    } else {
        seconds = intSeconds+" ";
    } 

    timeString = hours+minutes+seconds+ap;
    Clock.innerHTML = timeString;
    window.setTimeout(tick, 100);
}
window.onload = tick;
```